# Django error: Reverse for 'details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments

Tags: python, regex, django, url

Here is part of my django app and I want to create link with get_absolute_url but I get an error:

```
Reverse for 'details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'product'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

My model:

```
class PortfolioItem(models.Model):
    name_item = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    date_from = models.DateField('date from')
    date_to = models.DateField('date to')
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_item

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('details', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Here is my view:

```
class PortfolioDetail(DetailView):
    model = PortfolioItem
    template_name = "portfoliodetail.html"
```

Here is my url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PortfolioList.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^portfolio/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', PortfolioDetail.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here is an template:

```
<ul>
    {% for i in portfolioitem_list %}
        <li><a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}">{{ i.name_item }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `lol != details`, what is the actual code you're using?

Comment: @Sayse sorry, corrected!

Comment: Are those urls namespaced?

Comment: yes, under this address: `url(r'^portfolio/', include('portfolio.urls', namespace='portfolio')),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the namespace when referencing the url

```
return reverse('portfolio:details', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! @sayse